# Save image view as a jpeg image in sdcard

Tags: android

```
public class MapDemoActivity extends Activity {

Button capture;

    ImageView image;
    int cameracode=100;
    Bitmap bm;
    Boolean result;
    FileOutputStream fos;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        capture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
                Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(i, cameracode);
                image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                bm = image.getDrawingCache();

                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("sdcard/image.jpg");
                    result=bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(requestCode==100)
                    {

                        bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        image.setImageBitmap(bm);


                    }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

In this prog i am capturing image from camera & display to Image view then i am trying to 
convert it to Jpeg to store in sdcard...
But when i pressed **capture image** Button prog get force close..
& empty jpeg file created in sdcard... i want to store jpeg file to sdcard

Answer (score 1):

`startActivityForResult` is an asynchronous call, therefore everything that you have right after that call is executed immediately, before waiting for the capture to complete.  Instead of having it that way, you should move the saving code into the `onActivityResult`.

Additionally, you should not hardcode `sdcard` but instead use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    capture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameracode);
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(requestCode==100)
    {

        bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        if(bm == null) {
            return; //probably user cancelled;
        }

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg"));
            result=bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Finally, you may want to check that you actually got an image before trying to save it, as the user may have cancelled image capture.

Apart from it, I suggest that you post your full logcat stack trace. Maybe there's something else sinister in there.

Comment: Admittedly much more thorough than my answer.  This guy has your answer.

Comment: it works ...but now after capturing image by using camera prog get force close

Comment: please add the logcat stack trace to your question

Comment: >06-28 09:18:50.520: E/AndroidRuntime(286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {map.demo/map.demo.MapDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Please add _the whole_ stacktrace, not just one line.  Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: bm does not contain anything  i.e i get bm=null

Comment: @AleksG i posted new question Title -camera image conversion please help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your target directory to this:

```
try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/MyActivity/image.jpg");
                result=bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
```

Make sure you create your directory before writing to it as well.

```
            String dir  = "/mnt/sdcard/MyActivity/";
        directory = new File(dir);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the part of code after startActivityForResult is executed, and the bitmap is not yet available. You should save it directly on the onActivityResult.

Futhermore, have you ask Android to save you image by giving the intent this :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) );   
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

getTempFile is a function which returns me the path I want.

PS: Have you ask for the permission in the manifest ? You need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```